# Winform Dynamic Alignment

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-c#-express-2010

I'm attempting to dynamically add a series of controls to a form, but the primary problem is that they are completely misaligned. I've tried updated the control information and fixed minor problems but they are still misaligned.

I'm unsure what I'm missing on the alignment problem:

```
public void loadSkill(string skillName)
    {
        FlowLayoutPanel panel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
        standardSkillsLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(panel);
        panel.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        panel.Height = 28;
        panel.Width = 450;

        Label skillLabel = new Label();
        panel.Controls.Add(skillLabel);
        skillLabel.MinimumSize = new Size(120, 20);
        skillLabel.MaximumSize = new Size(120, 20);
        skillLabel.Text = skillName;
        skillLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        skillLabel.Dock = DockStyle.Left;

        Label skillStats = new Label();
        panel.Controls.Add(skillStats);
        skillStats.Text = "DEX + STR";
        skillStats.MinimumSize = new Size(80, 20);
        skillStats.MaximumSize = new Size(80, 20);
        skillStats.Margin = new Padding(3, 0, 3, 0);
        skillStats.Dock = DockStyle.Left;

        Label skillBasePercent = new Label();
        panel.Controls.Add(skillBasePercent);
        skillBasePercent.MinimumSize = new Size(60, 20);
        skillBasePercent.MaximumSize = new Size(60, 20);
        skillBasePercent.Text = "10";
        skillBasePercent.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
        skillBasePercent.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(210, 0);

        NumericUpDown skillCulturalUpdown = new NumericUpDown();
        panel.Controls.Add(skillCulturalUpdown);
        skillCulturalUpdown.MinimumSize = new Size(40, 20);
        skillCulturalUpdown.MaximumSize = new Size(40, 20);
        skillCulturalUpdown.Margin = new Padding(3, 0, 3, 0);
        skillCulturalUpdown.Value = 0;
        skillCulturalUpdown.Dock = DockStyle.Left;

        NumericUpDown skillProfessionalUpdown = new NumericUpDown();
        panel.Controls.Add(skillProfessionalUpdown);
        skillProfessionalUpdown.MinimumSize = new Size(40, 20);
        skillProfessionalUpdown.MaximumSize = new Size(40, 20);
        skillProfessionalUpdown.Margin = new Padding(3, 0, 3, 0);
        skillProfessionalUpdown.Value = 0;
        skillProfessionalUpdown.Dock = DockStyle.Left;

        NumericUpDown bonusUpDown = new NumericUpDown();
        panel.Controls.Add(bonusUpDown);
        bonusUpDown.Value = 0;
        bonusUpDown.MinimumSize = new Size(40, 20);
        bonusUpDown.MaximumSize = new Size(40, 20);
        bonusUpDown.Margin = new Padding(3, 0, 3, 0);
        bonusUpDown.Dock = DockStyle.Left;

        Label skillTotalPercent = new Label();
        panel.Controls.Add(skillTotalPercent);
        skillTotalPercent.Text = "10";
        skillTotalPercent.MinimumSize = new Size(50, 20);
        skillTotalPercent.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
    }
```

[image: misaligned rows]

Comment: Define 'completely misaligned'! Or draw the problems into the image..!

Comment: The two top rows are aligned fine. The third row is the problem.

Comment: [Here's an image displaying the misalignment.](http://i.imgur.com/tpjyg42.png)

Comment: Better use a `TableLayoutPanel` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492143.aspx instead of a `FlowLayoutPanel`. Less hassle and easier to align.

Comment: Do you really think that showing the code for only the third rows would be of any help to tell you why it is not aligned with previous rows? Obviously, some controls have different sizes than those in the first 2 rows.

Comment: An alternative to using a table layout would be to create a user control to ensure same size/position are used everywhere.

Comment: or `DataRepeater` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.datarepeater